# Acumatica API - Creating an appointment detail marked for PO

Tags: json, api, acumatica

I want to create an appointment detail line that is marked for PO. I'm setting the fields I think are relevant, but after the PUT, the MarkforPO field will reset to false. The detail record is created, but not marked for PO or any errors returned. Is there a process or specific field/value that I am missing?

Here is my Appointment PUT JSON:

```
{
  "id": "[APPOINTMENT GUID]",
  "Details": [
    {
        "LineRef": {
            "value": "0003"
        },
        "LineNbr": {
            "value": 3
        },
        "LineType": {
            "value": "Non-stock item"
        },
        "MarkforPO": {
            "value": true
        },
        "POSource": {
            "value": "Purchase to Appointment"
        },
        "InventoryID": {
            "value": "INVID"
        },
        "Description": {
            "value": "INVENTORY DESC"
        },
        "EstimatedQty": {
            "value": "1"
        },
        "Billable":{
            "value":true
        },
        "UnitPrice": {
            "value": "25"
        },
        "BillableQty": {
            "value": "1"
        },
        "BillableAmount": {
            "value": "25"
        },
        "UnitCost": {
            "value": "25"
        },
        "VendorID": {
            "value": "AASERVICES"
        },
        "VendorLocationID": {
            "value": "MAIN"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the URL in your PUT command?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble was that the AppDetails.MarkforPO field was not linked to a field but mapped to `FSSODet__EnablePO` instead. I am not sure what this is but after adding adding another custom field directly mapped to `Mark for PO` I was able to modify this field through the API.